# Render Info left on video

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I used the video-sequence-editor and after I rendered, all the render info was left on the video. Such as:

> The file location, Date, Render time and time code

The output file format I used was H.264
How do I remove this?

Comment: There is really no way to remove it. All you can do is rerender a clean version without the stamp output enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can enable this *Stamp Output* in a Properties View in the Render Panel (where you set your Render Dimensions as well) in its Metadata Panel:
[image: Metadata Panel]